# Create a Shape dynamically

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a shape object defined in XML like below:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#333"
        android:centerColor="#DDD"
        android:endColor="#333"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF333333" />
</shape>
```

I want to create an equal object in my code. 
I created a `GradientDrawable` as below:

```
gradientDrawable1.setColors(new int[] { 0x333, 0xDDD, 0x333 });
gradientDrawable1.setOrientation(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM);
```

But I don't know how to create a Stroke(?) and then assign both Stroke and `GradientDrawable` to `Shape`

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;

public class SomeDrawable extends GradientDrawable {

    public SomeDrawable(int pStartColor, int pCenterColor, int pEndColor, int pStrokeWidth, int pStrokeColor, float cornerRadius) {
        super(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP,new int[]{pStartColor,pCenterColor,pEndColor});
        setStroke(pStrokeWidth,pStrokeColor);
        setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SomeDrawable vDrawable = new SomeDrawable(Color.BLACK,Color.GREEN,Color.LTGRAY,2,Color.RED,50);
        View vView = new View(this);
        vView.setBackgroundDrawable(vDrawable);
        setContentView(vView);
    }


}
```

Result:

[image: Drawable result image]

Answer (score 0):

this should **surely work**, **Try**  `gradientDrawable1.setStroke(1, getResources().getColor(R.color.stroke));`

**so your code should be** :

```
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable1 = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.start),getResources().getColor(R.color.center),getResources().getColor(R.color.start)} );
    gradientDrawable1.setStroke(1, getResources().getColor(R.color.stroke));
```

where **color stroke,start,center** is defined inside `colors.xml` **as:**

```
 <color name="stroke">#FF333333</color>
 <color name="start">#333</color> 
 <color name="center">#ddd</color>
```

Answer (score -5):

if you want to make it in the code, first inspect what class instance is returned by res.getDrawable(resId) e.g by:

```
Drawable d = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.shape)
Log.d(TAG, "d: " + d)
```

Comment: I don't want to get object from resources. I want to create it dynamically in java code.

Comment: did you do what i wrote? what was the output?