# Width and Height Custom Textview with stroke not work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom TextView to set stroke lines, and root layout for this TextView is RelativeLayout with wrap_content, but when i change stroke size, width and height in layout cant adjust with TextView size with stroke, and stroke truncated with layout.
This is my custom TextView :

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextViewCustom extends TextView {

    private static final int DEFAULT_OUTLINE_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF");
    private static final int DEFAULT_OUTLINE_SIZE = 0;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_OUTLINE_STATE = true;

    private int outlineColor;
    private int outlineSize;
    private boolean outlineState;

    public TextViewCustom(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TextViewCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TextViewCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        outlineColor = DEFAULT_OUTLINE_COLOR;
        outlineSize = DEFAULT_OUTLINE_SIZE;
        outlineState = DEFAULT_OUTLINE_STATE;
    }

    public int getOutlineColor() {
        return outlineColor;
    }

    public void setOutlineColor(int outlineColor) {
        this.outlineColor = outlineColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getOutlineSize() {
        return outlineSize;
    }

    public void setOutlineSize(int outlineSize) {
        this.outlineSize = outlineSize;
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean getOutlineState() {
        return outlineState;
    }

    public void setOutlineState(boolean state) {
        outlineState = state;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (outlineState) {
            getPaint().setColor(outlineColor);
            getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            getPaint().setStrokeWidth(outlineSize);

            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft() + outlineSize, getCompoundPaddingTop());

            getLayout().draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }

        getPaint().setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(outlineSize, 0);

        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
        setTextColor(getTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
        setHintTextColor(getHintTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
        setLinkTextColor(getLinkTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
        getBackground().setAlpha(alpha);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override onDraw() method isn't a good way to do TextView with stroke. Instead of you should use xml and set it as background of TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="your stoke color" />
   <solid android:color="your background color" />
</shape>
```

And in layout

```
<TextView ... android:background="@drawable/your xml file" />
```

Comment: I want to set stroke programmatically and dynamically.. so if i set using xml isn't a solution..

Comment: @NafianWildana you can create shape by code and set it as background of textview. Override onDraw will cause some problem that we can't handle it.

Comment: can you give me example to do this with java code to change stroke width dynamically? because i set value of stroke size in method setOutlineSize() in my custom textview class.

Comment: You can take a look at this answered question [create-a-shape-dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759732/create-a-shape-dynamically)

Comment: This is just set stroke to textview area and result give me stroke in box outside textview, not in stroke in text, i want to set stroke on text area...